# onCreateOptionsMenu inside Fragments

Tags: android, android-fragments, layout-inflater, oncreateoptionsmenu

I have placed `setHasOptionsMenu(true)` inside `onCreateView`, but I still can't call `onCreateOptionsMenu` inside fragments.

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, 
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {   
   setHasOptionsMenu(true);             
   return inflater.inflate(R.layout.facesheet, container, false);
}
```

Below is my `onCreateOptionsMenu` code.

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(com.actionbarsherlock.view.Menu menu) {
    getSupportMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.layout, menu);
    return (super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu));
}
```

The error message I get:

> The method `onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu)` of type Fragment must override or implement a supertype method.

Comment: Thanks for the 'setHasOptionsMenu(true);', I was looking for that.

Answer (score 554, accepted):

try this,

```
@Override
public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu_sample, menu);
    super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu,inflater);
}
```

---

Finally, in `onCreateView` method, add this line to make the options appear in your `Toolbar`

```
setHasOptionsMenu(true);
```

Comment: For some reason onCreateOptionsMenu is not called in my Fragment

Comment: it won't be called if you don't add this line: `setHasOptionsMenu(true);`

Comment: onCreateOptionsMenu() for fragments has different arguments than for Activities.

Comment: and also a different return type as void unlike boolean of onCreateOptionsMenu() in activity as mentioned on above ans.

Comment: Interesting note: if you also override onCreateOptionsMenu in your containing Activity, both options menu items will be displayed.

Comment: `setHasOptionsMenu(true);` has to be called in `onCreate()` to be complete.

Comment: How to avoid show "action_settings" in fragment options?

Answer (score 24):

Your already have the autogenerated file **res/menu/menu.xml** defining **action_settings**.

In your **MainActivity.java** have the following methods:

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    int id = item.getItemId();
    switch (id) {
        case R.id.action_settings:
            // do stuff, like showing settings fragment
            return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item); // important line
}
```

In the `onCreateView()` method of your Fragment call:

```
setHasOptionsMenu(true);
```

and also add these 2 methods:

```
@Override
public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.fragment_menu, menu);
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    int id = item.getItemId();
    switch (id) {
        case R.id.action_1:
            // do stuff
            return true;

        case R.id.action_2:
            // do more stuff
            return true;
    }

    return false;
}
```

Finally, add the new file **res/menu/fragment_menu.xml** defining **action_1** and **action_2**.

This way when your app displays the Fragment, its menu will contain 3 entries:

- **action_1** from **res/menu/fragment_menu.xml**
- **action_2** from **res/menu/fragment_menu.xml**
- **action_settings** from **res/menu/menu.xml**

Comment: the question was inside fragments, not activity

Comment: @OlivierM the answer does explain the fragment menu. I appreciated the explanation of how it interacts with the activity menu.

Comment: How to avoid show "action_settings" in fragment options?

Answer (score 14):

I tried the @Alexander Farber and @Sino Raj answers. Both answers are nice, but I couldn't use the onCreateOptionsMenu inside my fragment, until I discover what was missing:

Add setSupportActionBar(toolbar) in my Activity, like this:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.id.activity_main);

    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
}
```

I hope this answer can be helpful for someone with the same problem.

Answer (score 6):

Call

```
setSupportActionBar(toolbar)
```

inside

```
onViewCreated(...)
```

of Fragment

```
@Override
public void onViewCreated(View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) view.findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    ((MainActivity)getActivity()).setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    setHasOptionsMenu(true);
}
```

Comment: Thank you fixed my problem

Answer (score 4):

Set setHasMenuOptions(true) works if application has a theme with Actionbar such as `Theme.MaterialComponents.DayNight.DarkActionBar` or `Activity` has it's own Toolbar, otherwise `onCreateOptionsMenu` in fragment does not get called.

If you want to use standalone `Toolbar` you either need to get activity and set your `Toolbar` as support action bar with

```
(requireActivity() as? MainActivity)?.setSupportActionBar(toolbar)
```

which lets your fragment onCreateOptionsMenu to be called.

Other alternative is, you can inflate your `Toolbar`'s own menu with `toolbar.inflateMenu(R.menu.YOUR_MENU)` and item listener with

```
toolbar.setOnMenuItemClickListener {
   // do something
   true
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
 @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_add_customer, container, false);
        setHasOptionsMenu(true);
}

@Override
public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu_sample, menu);
    super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu,inflater);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do easily as,
inside your fragment on Create method,

```
setHasOptionsMenu(true)
```

and now you can override,

```
override fun onCreateOptionsMenu(menu: Menu, inflater: MenuInflater) {
    super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu, inflater)
    menu.clear()
}
```