# Can't make MenuItem visible again

Tags: android, menu, menuitem

I have a `MenuItem` which I want to make it visible when only `ChatListFragment` of the `FragmentTabHost` is selected:

```
<menu
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <item
        android:id="@+id/action_start_chat"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_add_black_48dp"
        android:title="@string/action_bar_add_text"
        app:showAsAction="always"
        android:visible="true"/>

</menu>
```

So I am making it invisable in MainActivity:

```
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
    this.menu = menu;
    addChatItem = menu.findItem(R.id.action_start_chat);
    addChatItem.setVisible(false);
    return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
}
```

It is invisable in `LoginFragment` as I want but I can't make it visible again from `ChatListFragment` using public metod of the `MainActivity`:

MainActivity:

```
public void setAddChatVisibility(boolean visible) {
    addChatItem.setVisible(visible);
    invalidateOptionsMenu();
    supportInvalidateOptionsMenu();
}
```

ChatListFragment:

```
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_conversation, container, false);
    mainActivity = (MainActivity) getActivity();
    mainActivity.setAddChatVisibility(true);
    return view;
}
```

How can I do that? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

after invalidateOptionsMenu called method onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) in activity called again cause visible value set false.

you can use onCreateOptionMenu inside fragment
[onCreateOptionsMenu inside Fragments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15653737/oncreateoptionsmenu-inside-fragments)

Sorry for my bad english

Comment: Perhaps you could improve your answer a little bit.