# How can we set menu to toolbar

Tags: android, layout, menu

[image]I have a activity and fragment ,i want to set a menu to mytoolbar in pre run time the icon has set but in run application it does not show anything.

in my activity:

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

```
private TabLayout mTabLayout;
private TextView mTextViewTabOne;
private TextView mTextViewTabTwo;
private TextView mTextViewTabThree;
private android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar mToolbar;
private TextView mTextViewToolbarTitle;
private AlertDialog mAlertDialog;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    setLocale("fa");


    getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.framelayout_mainactivity_fragmentcontainer, new AuthenticationPasswordFragment()).commit();
    setToolBar(getString(R.string.addbank_toolbartitle));

}

public void setToolBar(String title) {


    mToolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbar_everywhere_toolbar);
    mTextViewToolbarTitle = findViewById(R.id.toolbar_title);

    mTextViewToolbarTitle.setText(title);

}
```

and in my fragment :

public class AuthenticationPasswordFragment extends BaseFragment implements BaseAuthenticationContract.View {

```
private TextInputEditText mEditTextPassword;
private TextInputLayout mTextInputEditTextPassword;
private View mRoot;

@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    mRoot=inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_authenticationpassword,null);

    return mRoot;
}
@Override
public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.authenticationpassword_menutoolbar,menu);
}
```

in my menu is:

```
<item
    android:id="@+id/item_authenticationpassword_confirm"
    android:title="confirm"
    android:icon="@drawable/everywhere_confirm"
    app:showAsAction="always"
    />
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace this setToolbar in activity :

```
public void setToolBar(String title,int resourceMenu) {

        mToolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbar_everywhere_toolbar);
        mTextViewToolbarTitle = findViewById(R.id.toolbar_title);
        mTextViewToolbarTitle.setText(title);
        mToolbar.inflateMenu(resourceMenu);

    }
```

With this :

```
public void setToolBar(String title) {

        mToolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbar_everywhere_toolbar);
        mTextViewToolbarTitle = findViewById(R.id.toolbar_title);
        mTextViewToolbarTitle.setText(title);

    }
```

And add this line to your onCreateView fragment or any fragment that you want add menu toolbar to it :

```
((MainActivity)getActivity()).setToolBar(getString(R.string.authenticationpassword_titletoolbar),R.menu.authenticationpassword_menutoolbar);
```

Answer (score 1):

In the activity's onCreate method, set the toolbar with

```
Toolbar toolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
```

Then add this method.

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
  getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.yourmenufile, menu);
  return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
}
```

Then add menu click listener,

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case 0:
            // do whatever
            return true;
        default:
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

If you want to change the menu items and listeners while in different fragments, use interfaces to let the activity know which fragment is active and change accordingly.

Comment: I have setTheToolbar in the oncreate activity and i use onCreateOptionMenu in fargment too

Comment: please close the question and if his answer is proper better give him solution sign.

Answer (score 0):

If you want the method `onCreateOptionsMenu` inside a Fragment, add the codeline `toolbar.setHasOptionsMenu(true)` in `onCreate` of the activity where the Toolbar is set up.
The second option is to move the `onCreateOptionsMenu` into the Activity.

See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15653737/8331157) related StackOverflow question.

Report back if this works, I hope it helps you.