# onCreateOptionsMenu not being called

Tags: java, android, android-studio, kotlin, optionmenu

onCreateOptionsMenu does not get called in a fragment. I have to manually call `setHasOptionsMenu(true)` in `onCreatedView()` but this causes the `item.itemId` be an empty String `""` in the `onOptionsItemSelected()` and therefore i can't detect which menu item was tapped.

I'm currently using this in a fragment:

```
override fun onCreateOptionsMenu(menu: Menu, inflater: MenuInflater) {
    super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu, inflater)
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu_font_share, menu)
}

override fun onOptionsItemSelected(item: MenuItem): Boolean {
    when (item.itemId) {
        R.id.menu_font_size_Btn -> {

        }
        R.id.menu_share_Btn -> {
            super.showShareSheet()
        }
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item)
}
```

Comment: @DhavalShah no. I already tried that. Read the question again

Comment: You have to set actionBar:         `setHasOptionsMenu(true);
        ((AppCompatActivity) getActivity()).setSupportActionBar(toolbar);`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Call `super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu,inflater)` after menu inflate

```
override fun onCreateOptionsMenu(menu: Menu, inflater: MenuInflater) {
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu_font_share, menu)
    super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu,inflater)
}
```

This may more help
Ref :: https://stackoverflow.com/a/15654039/11393354

try this,

```
@Override
public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu_sample, menu);
    super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu,inflater);
}
```

---

And in `onCreate` add this line to make the options appear in your `Toolbar`

```
setHasOptionsMenu(true);
```

Answer (score 3):

To make `onCreateOptionsMenu` work inside your fragment you can follow the below steps:

Be sure to set your Toolbar as ActionBar (if using one):

styles.xml

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.DayNight.NoActionBar">
    ...
</style>
```

In your Activity's `onCreate`:

```
setSupportActionBar(my_toolbar)
```

Without this line, `onOptionsItemSelected` event won't run inside your fragment. This assigns all the ActionBar callbacks to Toolbar.

In your fragments `onViewCreated` or `onCreateView` :

```
setHasOptionsMenu(true)
```

And also override this method:

```
override fun onOptionsItemSelected(item: MenuItem): Boolean {
    when (item.id) {
        R.id.item_01 -> {}
        R.id.item_02 -> {}
        ...
    }
    super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu, inflater)
}
```

**If you are using Android Navigation Component add this in your Activity:**

```
setupActionBarWithNavController(navController)
```

Answer (score 1):

[Fragment-owned app bar](https://developer.android.com/guide/fragments/appbar#fragment): In case you have your `Toolbar` defined in your `Fragment` layout and *not* in the layout of the parent `Activity`, you should use the Toolbar APIs to inflate the menu. (Fragment menu APIs are appropriate only for activity-owned app bars)

Fragment Layout

```
<androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
    ... />
```

Fragment

```
override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {

    ...
    val toolbar = binding.toolbar
    toolbar.inflateMenu(R.menu.sample_menu)
    toolbar.setOnMenuItemClickListener {
            when (it.itemId) {
                R.id.action_settings -> {
                    // Navigate to settings screen
                    true
                }
                R.id.action_done -> {
                    // Save profile changes
                    true
                }
                else -> false
            }
        }

    //set item visibility
    toolbar.menu.findItem(R.id.action_done).isVisible = ...
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 override fun onCreateOptionsMenu(menu: Menu?): Boolean {
    menuInflater.inflate(R.menu.menu, menu)
    return true
}

 override fun onOptionsItemSelected(item: MenuItem): Boolean {
    // Handle item selection
    return when (item.getItemId()) {
        R.id. menu_font_size_Btn -> {
           //your TODO
            true
        }
        else -> super.onOptionsItemSelected(item)
    }
   }
```

Comment: `onCreateOptionsMenu(menu: Menu?): Boolean` does not exist.