# SherlockFragment onCreateOptionsMenu is not calling

Tags: android, android-fragments, actionbarsherlock, oncreateoptionsmenu, pagerslidingtabstrip

In my app I'm having a class which extends **SherlockFragmentActivity**. Within that Activity, I'm loading four classes which extends **SherlockFragment** which pretends as *Tabs* with the help of ***ActionbarSherlock*** and ***PagerSlidingTabStrip***.

The classes which extends **SherlockFragment** has ***setHasOptionsMenu(true);*** inside ***onCreate()*** method. Even having that, when run the application, it won't call ***onCreateOptionsMenu()*** method.

I have read these similar questions ([Q1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11855581/how-can-i-use-oncreateoptionsmenu-in-a-fragment-within-a-tab-activity-sherlock?rq=1), [Q2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15653737/oncreateoptionsmenu-inside-fragments)) in SO and didn't get any help.

What can be the reason for that?

---

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setHasOptionsMenu(true);

}

@Override
public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {
    menu.clear();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.record, menu);
    super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu, inflater);
    Log.i(TAG, "* onCreateOptionsMenu");
}
```

---

**UPDATE:**

I think the reason is, I'm using SherlockFragment inside another SherlockFragment. Means in [PageSlidingTabStripFragment.java](https://github.com/astuetz/PagerSlidingTabStrip/blob/master/sample/src/com/astuetz/viewpager/extensions/sample/MainActivity.java) has following method inside **MyPagerAdapter** class.

```
@Override
public SherlockFragment getItem(int position) {
    return SuperAwesomeCardFragment.newInstance(position);
}
```

What I'm doing is, I'm calling some other SherlockFragments from there like below.

```
@Override
public SherlockFragment getItem(int position) {
    Log.i(TAG, "* getItem");

    switch (position) {
        case 0:
            return new InnerSherlockFragmentOne();
        case 1:
            return new InnerSherlockFragmentTwo();
        case 2:
            return new InnerSherlockFragmentThree();
        case 3:
            return new InnerSherlockFragmentFour();
        default:
            return null;
    }
}
```

What is not calling is **onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater)** inside those InnerSherLockFragments.

Comment: Maybe you forgot to add `menu.clear()` before inflating the menu.

Comment: @Naddy No... I'm telling that `onCreateOptionsMenu()` not even call. If I put a `Log` message inside that method as first line, it won't print.

Comment: @Naddy added to the question now

Comment: I have implemented the same code and it's working for me. The only difference being that I have created the **MenuItems** programmatically. Are you using **MapFragment**??

Comment: @Naddy I'm not using MapFragment. Me too can create `MenuItems` programmatically. But to create `MenuItems` programatically we need to fire `onCreateOptionsMenu()` inside Fragment. That is the place not happening to me. You may have implemented the `MenuItems` inside `SherlockFragmentActivity` not `SherlockFragment` OR you may not creating different `MenuItems` for different Fragments. By the way, thanks for sharing your experience.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/41514/discussion-between-anujarosha-and-naddy)

Comment: This is not the solution. But I achieved this by removing ActionbarSherlock and using only PageSlidingTabStrip.

Answer (score 4):

The imports should be:

```
import com.actionbarsherlock.view.Menu;
import com.actionbarsherlock.view.MenuItem;
```

and not these of android OS!

Also try calling `super` method like:

```
@Override
public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {
    super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu, inflater);
    menu.clear();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.record, menu);

    Log.i(TAG, "* onCreateOptionsMenu");
}
```

Comment: @AnujAroshA are you sure that the activity on does not disable the menu? add methods also to the activity to test if it functions...

Comment: Actually, if I'm creating Menu items in `onCreateOptionsMenu()`  inside my Activity class which extends `SherlockFragmentActivity` it will display in the Menu. But then I'm not able to change Menu items according to the Fragment changes. That's why I'm trying to implement Menu items inside each Fragment Activity.

Answer (score 2):

I had a same issue recently. And my code is very similar with yours that I use Fragment in PagerSlidingTabStrip...

My solution is something like this.

I don't do anything in my fragment but fix the source from PageSlidingTabStripFragment.java

PageSlidingTabStripFragment.java

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    adapter = new MainPagerAdapter(getChildFragmentManager());
    setHasOptionsMenu(true);
setRetainInstance(true);
}

@Override
public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {
    Log.e("test", "Fragment onCreateOptionsMenu");
    int position = pager.getCurrentItem();

    if (position == 4) {
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.fragment_report_menu, menu);
    }

    super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu, inflater);
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.board_list_menu_new:
            ReportFragment fragment = (ReportFragment) adapter.getItem(pager.getCurrentItem());
            fragment.onMyOptionItemSelected();
            break;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

And that all.

This is not very clean solution and should be fixed in library. :)

Thanks,
Wooram

Answer (score 1):

This is the exact code I have written and it works fine.

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;

import com.actionbarsherlock.app.SherlockFragment;
import com.actionbarsherlock.view.Menu;
import com.actionbarsherlock.view.MenuInflater;
import com.actionbarsherlock.view.MenuItem;

public class First extends SherlockFragment {
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        setHasOptionsMenu(true);

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        Log.i("TAG", "* created");
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {
        super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu, inflater);
        menu.clear();
        menu.add("abcd").setShowAsAction(MenuItem.SHOW_AS_ACTION_ALWAYS);
        menu.add("efgh").setShowAsAction(MenuItem.SHOW_AS_ACTION_ALWAYS);

        Log.i("TAG", "* onCreateOptionsMenu");
    }
}
```

Comment: I've update the question. Please add your experience with that. Thanks